# How Would Seven-League Boots Affect the Body?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, health

One recurring element of European folklore is a magical item called the seven-league boot.  Traditionally, it allows the wearer to take strides of seven leagues per step.

The problem with this imagery is that seven leagues translate to 21 miles.  It would stretch the body beyond the laws of physics, so I have re-described the seven-league boots' powers as:

- Doubling, even tripling, the wearer's top speed
- Allowing the wearer to run that extra-fast speed for seven leagues at once, hence the name of the item

In regards to health and ignoring any kind of magical protection or plot armor aiding the wearer, could the powers of a similar magical equipment (with mostly the same powers) exhaust every organ in the body to the point of death?

Comment: I assumed some Lorentz contraction was at play for normal use.

Comment: You'd be going ridiculously fast: https://www.google.com/search?q=7+leagues+per+second+to+miles+per+hour&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS778US778&oq=7+leagues+per+second+to+miles+per+hour

Comment: Expanding, that's ~87,000 MPH, or 5.07 times faster than the fastest man-made craft that currently exists, the ISS.

Comment: A "**magical** item" would "stretch the body **beyond the laws of physics**".  Naturally!  What's your point?

Comment: @NexTerren So about 113 times the speed of sound.... yeah, the wearer is getting their face ripped off.

Comment: @Tim no, because magic.

Comment: @NexTerren  I said doubling or tripling top speed.  For a human, that's either 40 or 60 miles per hour at a length of 21 miles.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it really can't be answered. Once you've thrown in these magic boots that allow you to change the limits of the human body, you can't ask what happens to the human body, because your magic defines it, and you haven't defined your magic system. If your magic boots don't do that, then all you're asking is "can a person run this fast, and if they do for this long, what happens", which isn't a worldbuilding question.

Comment: @NexTerren - I think you've made one small mistake.  "seven leagues per step" you've taken to mean "seven leagues per second".   If it was a 10 minute step, this person would only be travelling (only) around 144mph.    I guess to OP...how long is the 'step' in question here?

Comment: Why must there be a presumption that worldbuilding has limitations?

Comment: A well built world has rules and limitations, just like Earth.  If you remove those limitations (i.e.: anything is possible) then there's nothing to challenge your characters.  They would be unstoppable.  A world with limitations makes sense to a reader.  I'd suggest reading [Sanderson's Second Law](https://brandonsanderson.com/sandersons-second-law/)

Comment: @JohnWDailey following up on Tim's comment: how short would LoTR be if Sauron's power had no limits?

Comment: If the boots were magical stilts, you could have the wearer travel 21 miles in one step without the need to consider cartoonishly stretchy legs.  I could be wrong about this, but it might also cure the flag issue your question is having on this forum: it raises fun questions regarding how tall the wearer would be (geometry!), their difficult breathing (life science!), and the wake of destruction created by the bottoms of the stilts (physics!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"... would these powers exhaust every organ in the body to the point of death?"

## No

The boots are doing the work of giving the wearer extra energy, which allows them to cover more distance, faster.

So it stands to reason that the wearer thus exerts no more energy than if they were running normally.

They have to stop and rest eventually.  Top marathon runners, whose top speed is about 20 kph, can run for two hours but they're utterly exhausted afterward.

Such a runner, wearing your boots, would run at 60 kph, and be just as exhausted after two hours as if they ran normally.

Of course, because of your re-description, your boots are no longer 7-league boots.  So you couldn't really call them that.  They'd be Mercury boots, they speed you up.

---

If you were to use more traditional boots, which actually do carry a person 7 leagues with each step, you can still make them work.

Rather than have the person need to take one enormous, leg-stretching stride, you can have the person take a single, normal step, and then the boots rush them forward 7 leagues.

Take this video for example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFygAekjKSk

Sure, it's made with stop-motion.  But think of the idea - you take one step, then woosh - the boots carry you 7 leagues.  You don't have to move at all, the boots do the work.

Of course the boots would have to compensate for the terrain.  And you wouldn't want to be facing a cliff...

You could have fun with your character learning to use them, taking a step without thinking and finding themselves in a lake.  Or encountering bandits and just "stepping" past them.

Comment: I guess the boots would need inertial dampening of some form, lest the force of the boots speeding them up and stopping them squish the wearers internals.

Comment: Other ways seven league boots could work is by teleportation - maybe triggered by setting down their foot, or else passing one foot in front of the other; or else bending/warping space around the person walking...  at least that's how I always imagined they would work